# display a table after another table from a different file in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, web

I am showing two tables on top of my page from php_file1.php which is ajax based. Then in there is another table in body of the page which is shown after these two table. The thing is I need to display last table of php_file1.php after body's table. 
I cant modify anything in php side. Any way to do in front end?

Sharing code:
php_file1.php (ajax based):

```
echo "<table class='class1' id='class1' style='width:90%;'>";
// some stuffs
echo "</table>";
<br>
echo "<table class='class2' id='class2' style='width:90%;'>";
// some stuffs
echo "</table>";
```

In my page body

```
echo "<table class='body' id='body' style='width:90%;'>";
// some stuffs
echo "</table>";
```

I need to display id with class2 after id with body
I need to do it in run time only (javascript/jquery). I cant run any extra ajax because all data is in php_file1.php
My page loads first only then ajax loads.

Comment: Sharing what you have tried so far will help us to help you!

Comment: I was trying jQuery next() Method to print the table after , but didnt work.

Comment: You need show your code, so others can tell you how to fix it.

Comment: Better you share code, because jQuery next() should work and tested all around the world!

Comment: I have shared code.

Comment: when your file is php then you can create php function know..why you are trying in javascript

Comment: but how can i load function of ajax file after body's table. ajax loads later on after body loads.

Comment: try to learn about the use of Ajax..However you are going to create the php stuff for ajax..same you do in the php function and call it

Comment: Do you think that the code you shared give others ability to debug your problem with jQuery next()?